# How can I enable file path autocompletion in the IPython console in PyCharm?

Tags: autocomplete, ipython, pycharm

**Note**: The suboptimal autocompletion (not necessarily of file paths only, but autocompletion in general) is a known issue, and there seems to be no generic quality solution yet. **Please see the researched links below.**

Path autocompletion in the IPython console in PyCharm does not work well:

```
c:/U<TAB>
```

should autocomplete to:

```
cd c:/Users/
```

on my machine; instead, the best it manages is:

```
cd c:/UserWarning
```

which is plain wrong. IPython in the Anaconda prompt, however, behaves as it should.

My strong assumption (supported by a link, below) is that this is due to PyCharm not using the standard IPython configuration files.

I'm aware of the console starting script in PyCharm:

```
Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Console->Python console
```

and I've successfully used it to activate a simple magic command I've written.

So here my question: is there a code configuration snippet that could be inserted there, and that could just enable file path autocompletion? Or a pointer to a general description on how IPython configuration files "work", that would enable me to figure it out myself? That is, I imagine, the most doable hack that would solve the problem for the time being.

Alternatively, any experiences with writing your own autocompletion using the following libraries:

```
IPython.core.completer
IPython.core.completerlib
```

?

Is that doable? How much work can that be?

Thanks in advance!

---

**My SW-Setup:**

I use:

PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.1

Anaconda 2 (Python 2.7), version 4.3.22 which contains
IPython 5.1.0
on Windows 7 Professional N

---

**Links supporting claims in the question(s) above - just two, due to lack of StackOverflow-"reputation" :(**

*1) Autocompletion in IPython console in PyCharm not working as it should*

JetBrains (creators of PyCharm) knows about this since, at least, two years (please Google it under "PyCharm Console tab completion" or similar, I'm allowed to add just a limited number of links here), and seems to have started working on it, but never finished it.

The discussion states " this is only the initial step to getting full IPython tab completions": https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9345, but the issue is closed since October 2016.

On StackOverflow there are three questions with similar wording, but not one substantial answer (no, using  Ctrl+Space instead of Tab does not solve anything). Again, I can't add more links here.

_2) PyCharm not using ipython_config.py to configure IPython Console:_

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206603035-Which-ipython-config-py-is-used-to-configure-IPython-for-Python-Console-

See the comment by JetBrains at the end of the page.